# Angular .directive templateUrl not being requested

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm still learning angular, so I want to write my own controls to learn more about how angular works. I started off with a datepicker, since that is a control I do need occasionally and which has a lot of functionality embedded that never changes.

I got that datepicker up and running by declaring the `template` directly within the directive, but when I wanted to relocate the template to its own HTML-file, it started getting awkward.

According to the angular documentation, it should be possible to specify an outlying HTML-file for the template of the control, so I tried to do that as the control became more and more evolved.

The directive now is as follows:

```
angular.module('my.Controls', [])
.directive('myDatepicker', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        require: 'ngModel',
        templateUrl: '/Templates/my/DatePicker.html',
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
        // Some datepicker functionality
    }
}]);
```

and of course a HTML file for testing the directive to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular/current/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/my/Controls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['my.Controls']);
        var ctrl = app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.Date = new Date(2016, 08, 15);
        }]);

    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{Date}}
    <my-datepicker ng-model="Date" />
</body>
</html>
```

Now I can confirm that the .js files get loaded and that the app and controller are working. However since I changed the `template: '...'` property to `templateUrl: '...'` I cannot even verify that angular even tries to load the HTML file as I can't see any requests made for it.

What am I missing here? Why is angular not even trying to load the templatefrom the URL?

Comment: Is this a valid file `'my.DatePicker.html'` ?? Seems there is a dot after "my"

Comment: There is no trying or not trying to get the template. Your url is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, typo while editing out some info... it's actually a `/` but still doesn't work.

Comment: change your element to `<my-datepicker></my-datepicker>` (not self-closed)

Comment: Try removing the `/` at the beginning of the path: `templateUrl: 'Templates/my/DatePicker.html'`

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah @theaccordance Nope. The browser still doesn't even try to request the `HTML`. I can't even see a request for the HTML file, let alone a 404...

Comment: Is the `link` function getting called? I guess it's not. then the angular is not recognizing your directive for some reason, like wrong selector, unintegrated JS file or might be the module the directive belongs to is not imported to main module, if you're creating different modules.

Comment: Well in the end it turned out to be the browser cache... I still don't know why it didn't clear it from within the browser - although telling it to do so, but hard deleting all temporary files from explorer did the trick... Well that's one hour wasted then...

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your scripts.  I'd recommend moving your `myApp` module definition into a script file. I expect you might have console errors right now that are preventing your app from running correctly.  Because its working in the fiddle.

I made 3 changes to your script first is i just put them all in the inline script block to test (don't do this for prod put them in a  file).  I then removed the`/` from `Templates/my/DatePicker.html`  .  I hooked up the 1.5x version of angular.  Unless you are using Angular2 all of the below code should work fine.

```
angular.module('my.Controls', [])
    .directive('myDatepicker', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {},
            require: 'ngModel',
            templateUrl: 'Templates/my/DatePicker.html',
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
            // Some datepicker functionality
            }
        }
}]);


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['my.Controls']);
var ctrl = app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope)     {
       $scope.Date = new Date(2016, 08, 15);
}]);
```

Plunkr can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/AFw6xU2gRK756DNcDKpw?p=preview) .

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the there is html path and name is proper.  I am able to see that your template URL having some dot /Templates/m**y.D**atePicker.html. Replace with underscore(_) or hyphen(-) and check.

Comment: It really doesn't affect. you can divide you name using dots, dashed or underlines.